# Calling custom mongoDB query with spring data fails

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data

i am trying to call a custom mongoDB query using spring data, but query is not getting called.

Here is my code.

In Controller : call to service method

```
List<UserProfile> gatheringMembers = userService.getUsersProfile(membersEmail);
```

Here is service Method that is calling custom mongoDB query

```
public List<UserProfile> getUsersProfile(List<String> emails){
        return userProfileRepository.findAllUsersByEmail(emails);
    }
```

here is my mongoDB repository interface

```
public interface UserProfileRepository extends MongoRepository<UserProfile, String>, UserProfileRepositoryCustom {

    public UserProfile findByEmail(String email);

}
```

and here is interface

```
public interface UserProfileRepositoryCustom {

    public List<UserProfile> findAllUsersByEmail(List<String> emails);

}
```

and its implementation

```
public List<UserProfile> findAllUsersByEmail(List<String> emails) {
        logger.info("getting all users profiles");
        Query query = new Query(where("email").in(emails));
        return mongoOperations.find(query, UserProfile.class);
    }
```

when i run the code, i am getting empty list in controller. `findByEmail` is working fine. Can any one kindly help me whats wrong in this code.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a bit more, i found a solution to my answer, that was not the code problem but actually the configuration problem. For those who face the same problem i will add the solution. After adding `repository-impl-postfix="CustomImpl"` it started working.

Before :

```
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.app.repositories"/>
```

After :

```
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.app.repositories" repository-impl-postfix="CustomImpl" />
```